# Smallest algebraic eigenvalues (including negatives) using shift-invert mode Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the smallest algebraic eigenvalues and vectors for a bunch of different matrices using shift invert mode for speed (in Python using scipy eigsh). This works well for the small positive eigenvalues using the which='LA' criterion, but for small negative eigenvalues, using 'LA' doesn't give me the smallest algebraic eigenvalues, nor does 'LM', since there could be a smaller magnitude but positive eigenvalue that masks the negative one. Is there a mode in eigsh in which I can still use shift-invert yet be able to find these pesky negative eigenvalues, or will I have to resort to just sticking with 'SA' in the usual mode? If only there was an efficient way to determine if a matrix is positive-definite without doing any diagonalization, since that would tell you immediately if there are negative eigenvalues. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on the scipy-user list probably ( http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html ), and regarding diagonalization, ask on [MathExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)!